# Excel Compare Data in a COMPLEX REPORT

Tags: excel

I have an excel report which consists of 1,006 borrowers. Each borrower has multiple owners. What I want is that the excel should do a search on each owners and then group all the borrowers which have a common owner together so that I can give that group of borrowers a unique identifier name.

For example: the screen below shows names of different borrowers which have different owners. I want that the excel should compare each owner in different rows and then group all the borrowers which have common owners.

In this example Borrower “B1” and “B3” have a common owner “P2” and also Borrower “B5” is owned by borrower “B1” which has an owner “P2”. Therefore, all the borrowers B1, B2 & B5 are grouped together; whereas the borrower “B2” and “B4” are not grouped because they do not have any common owners.

Any help in solving this problem is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: But `B1` also has `P1` but `B3` does not. So why would `B1` and `B3` get the same identifier? What criteria determines what?

Comment: How are you looking to do this? VBA?

Comment: Yes but the common owner is P2 because it is present both in B1 & B3; so basically P2 is the most common principal. So the data should be grouped by P2.

Comment: I am working in excel and have no knowledge of VBA

Comment: Is this a one time thing or something you need to be able to repeat? If it's a one time thing you could do it with a grid but that will take a long tedious amount of time.

Comment: its a continuous process. Not a 1 time thing :(

Comment: Does the OWNER data some how indicate the OWNER is also a BORROWER? Like you have `B1` for `B5` so you know it is another BORROWER because it starts with `B`.

Comment: Yes the borrower can be a Owner also. Just like B5 is a new borrower but the owner of this borrower is B1 which is  listed in borrower coloumn.

Comment: I think this is possible but will require VBA. You could probably get it done using SQL left joins (through Microsoft Query) in Excel but that gets complicated really quickly because you'd need logic to account for certain situations. Like `B1` is `P1` and `P2` and `B5` is `B1` which is `P1` and `P2` so you could say `B1` and `B2` are one unique identifier and `B3` is another because it **is not** in `P1`. So do you short circuit like that or go for greatest common?